# Sinatra dynamic template name

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra, haml

I just started checking out sinatra for a project, and I started playing around with HAML.

However, I've run in to an issue -- I have a path with a splat that needs to point to an HAML file with a name the same as the text splatted out of the url, however, any string passed to the [haml] template method is treated as an inline template, and not a filename.

There is no documentation that would suggest there is a way to do this. The only solution I can think of is reading to full text of the necessary template file and passing it to the HAML function; however, such a solution is incredibly cumbersome.

Example

```
get '/stpl/*.haml' do |page|
    haml page # <--- `page' is treated as an inline template
end
```

Whilst this functionality is expected when one reads the documentation, there is no other means, it would seem, to accomplish what I need.

Comment: I would remove the haml suffix from the call since it is internal to the application. Sinatra will return html eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass a `symbol` to `haml`, it will look in `views` for the matching file, so you can do this instead:

```
get '/stpl/*.haml' do |page|
    haml page.to_sym # attempts to get views/<page>.haml
end
```